Seeking regular updated news about Coordinate Reference Systems related developments
I am looking for some news service I could sign up to which would provide news of important developments in the world of Coordinate Reference Systems - for example the creation of new map projections, datums etc.
I know I can find this out from analysing the EPSG dataset, for example, but I was wondering if there is somewhere which provides a more user-friendly "Latest developments" news service about such matters (and I can then investigate the specific details of these at my leisure).
I have been scouring around the internet for something like this for a while without success.

I don't know of anything like this. My colleague Bojan Savric does more social media than I do, for instance. He's likely to (re-)post map projection-related content. There's also an ISO geodetic registry. That might be your best source for new geodetic coordinate reference systems.
